# li text alignment issue in google chrome when li has fixed width

Tags: css

I have a div which consists of li's and i got some styles to show li's as list item as below

```
position: relative;
left: 20px;
display: list-item;
max-width: 160px;
font-size: 12px;
```

the problem is as the li has fixed width if the text is more than the width then it is displaying in second line. It works fine in all browsers except chrome. It displays in second line but second line is starting from bullet symbol i want that to be started from the place where text started in the first line.

```
Example:
    it is as below
     . xxxxxxxxx
     . yyyyyyyyy
     yyyyy

but i want as below
     . xxxxxxxxx
     . yyyyyyyyy
       yyyyy
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle.net and add to your question. So you can get a better help

Comment: you do not need `display: list-item;` if it is a `li` element

Comment: seems to work fine be me on webkit http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4y5JV/1/

Comment: @danield, i have parent div tag not ul does that make any diff. It works for me too but not working in chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display list items - the correct and most semantic way to do this is by using

An ordered/unordered list `<ul>` / `<ol>` with list items `<li>` as children.

This will also solve the problem you are facing.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/4y5JV/1/)

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li>lots of text</li>
    <li>lots of text</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
li
{
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    max-width: 160px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```